# How to Inject Dependency of ApplicationDbContext in Repository MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 6 beta4 with Repository Pattern.

In the my Startup.cs I have someting like this:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

//Dependency Injection
services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

In the my Controller I can get my instance of ApplicationDbContext with:

```
[FromServices]
public ApplicationDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
```

But I cannot get the instance of ApplicationDbContext in my Repository implementation with this self segment code above.

With MVC 5 I used ServiceLocator in my Repository and took the ApplicaionDbContext so:

```
var context = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

How to get the Instance of ApplicationDbContext in my repository with Asp.NET MVC 6?

Comment: Did you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332494/asp-net-vnext-dbcontext-dependency-injection-multiple-request-issues

Comment: I will arrive! Thank!

Comment: Why are you using property injection rather than constructor injection?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, With contruction injection I could get the instance just as caught with propert injection in MVC6? Because with [FromServices] I get the ApplicationDbContext in my session.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch as I do that?

Comment: @RenattoMachado - I can't understand what you're saying...What does session have to do with anything?

Comment: Sorry. Forget this part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want is to use AddScoped, and not AddTransient, so that the context will be cleand up properly when the request ends.

You also need to actually add the Context, not just the AddEntityFramework calls...

```
services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: So, in my injection repository would be made by constructor?

Comment: @RenattoMachado - I don't understand what you mean.. if you're asking if you should be using constructor injection, then yes, you should.. unless there is no other way, then property injection would be what you would use.. but only use property injection as a last resort.

Comment: I did what you said, but I got this error: `No data stores are configured. Configure a data store by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.`

Comment: @RenattoMachado - You still need the AddEntityFramework(...) stuff as well.

Comment: Would it be this? 
`services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));`

I did not remove this code.

Comment: @RenattoMachado - hmm.. that error typically indicates you haven't set up the DI for EF.  See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2156

Comment: I resolved with: `services.AddScoped<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationDbContext>();`
Change the answer that I mark as a solution.
Thank you very much for you patience.

Comment: @RenattoMachado -  Are you injecting an IdentityDbContext rather than an ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82862/discussion-between-renatto-machado-and-erik-funkenbusch).

Comment: FYI, `.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()` registers the context as a service. `.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>()` shouldn't be needed, and may be causing the error.